# output cmd line sql to csv

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, export-to-csv

Im trying to export some stuff into csv using

```
mysql> select
    -> sku,
    -> qty,
    -> shelf_location,
    -> notify_stock_qty as warning_stock_level,
    -> use_config_notify_stock_qty as use_config_warning_stock_level,
    -> ideal_stock_level,
    -> use_config_ideal_stock_level
    -> from
    -> catalog_product_entity
    -> inner join cataloginventory_stock_item on entity_id = product_id
    -> where
    -> type_id = 'simple'
    -> and stock_id = 1
    -> INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

i keep getting this back
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' (using password: YES)

can anyone show me what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: Well its nothing to do with the query, you have not even logged in yet

Comment: First check you have an account like that set with a domain of `%`